# How does one say beforehand beforehand?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar

Consider the following sentence:

> "It would need to be approved beforehand."

How would I say that in the following order:

> "It would need to be beforehand approved."

? What is the word that needs to replace "beforehand" in this sentence?

I have in mind that I've used such a construct in the past (and the same goes for "afterwards") but I can't seem to remember the word for it. "Priorly" is the best I can do, and it seems to be [archaic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/priorly). And "preliminarily" has a different connotation (though technically it might have been correct at some point).

Comment: Is there a problem with using 'It would need to be approved beforehand'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The emphasis. Within a paragraph, the order of the words would indicate an emphasis on either beforehand or approved.

Comment: The grammatical version (It would need to be approved beforehand.) stresses the need for **prior** approval. If there is a need to stress the approving, you would normally recast: 'This change will have to be approved before we can implement it.'

Comment: 'beforehand approved' is not grammatical in any variety of English that I am aware of. Are you just trying to jog your memory of a different way to say 'approval beforehand'? You haven't given any indication as to what tat alternate might be besides 'priorly' (and in a comment that 'prior' isn't right. That's not enough to go on for us to guess what used to be in your head.

Comment: Are you looking for the word *preapproved*?

Comment: It would need approval in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a word for the blank in the following to indicate prior approval:

- It would need to be ___ approved.

Consider *previously*.

> **previously** *adverb*
>   At a previous or earlier time; before.
>   ‘He has discovered a few previously unknown stars and made them into very good players.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/previously)

Here's an example of this usage:

> Leases to be previously approved by the Treasury.
>   [- The Statutes of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Ireland](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=I-xHAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA10&dq=%22to%20be%20previously%20approved%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNgbi2xaTWAhXGU7wKHTG_AgsQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22to%20be%20previously%20approved%22&f=false)

Comment: This looks very good. Thanks. But I now see that my question was actually a bit ambiguous, and that the sentence I'm looking for can mean `please get approval and then do it.` (which is what I meant) or `please check if it has been approved [before this conversation takes place] and only do it if it has.` . Would `previously` be appropriate in the first case? By the link ("The Statues...") that you've provided, it seems it is appropriate. Do you agree?

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence

> It would need to be approved beforehand.

is very good, but the next sentence

> It would need to be beforehand approved.

is awkward, perhaps trying to use your own language syntax. If you want to reverse the sentence structure I suggest

> It would need prior approval.

Comment: More than being awkward, I don't think 'beforehand approved' is even grammatical.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I just meant to explain what I'm looking for. If it would be correct, I wouldn't need to look further.

Comment: This is a nice workaround, though not exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Accepting because it's the closest to what I want so far.